# Bigquery: fail to change filed name

Tags: google-bigquery

We are changing filed naming convention to UpperCamelCase. Then we realized that if it's a single-word name, BQ just ignore any case changes. For example, when we ran the following query, all field names changed as we expected, except that 'speed', 'ignition','latitude' and 'longitude' just remained as they were in lower case....   I wonder if it's a bug or with special consideration? It gave us a huge issue when we are migrating our big data in thousands of tables into new naming convention

```
     SELECT  
            file_date_time AS FileLastModifiedTime  
            ,driver_id AS DriverId  
            ,date_time AS DateTime  
            ,latitude AS Latitude  
            ,longitude AS Longitude  
            ,gps_valid AS  GpsValid  
            ,ignition AS Ignition  
            ,speed AS SPEED  
            ,gps_reason AS GpsReason  
            ,zip_code AS ZipCode  
      FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug.  Field names in BigQuery are case-insensitive and you should be able to change the case of a field using aliases.  I've filed a bug internally.

A workaround is to do a no-op typecast, which will cause us to apply the alias with exact casing.
For example, if speed is an int: `SELECT ... INTEGER(speed) AS SPEED, ...`

Answer (score 2):

This is a quirk in BQ's schema generation, for reasons mentioned in your other answer.

One workaround is to use a subselect that renames the fields to an intermediate name:

```
SELECT LatitudeTmp AS Latitude FROM
  (SELECT latitude AS LatitudeTmp FROM MyTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, my guess is that BQ isn't case sensitive with field names when run queries. But the field name is case sensitive when do data streaming. Because records with filed name 'Ignition' wouldn't be streamed successfully to a table with 'ignition'